# Accessing an array using a pointer in a struct

Tags: c++

I wanted to access the array elements using the struct attributes. I am able to print 1st and the 2nd element using the struct pointer (*nameptr) while the remaining 3 elements has to be accessed using the (uint8_t* ptr) which itself is a attribute of the 'struct name'.

```
#include <iostream>

struct name{

    uint8_t b0;
    uint8_t b1;
    uint8_t* ptr;

}*nameptr;

int main()
{
    
    uint8_t arr[]= {1,2,3,4,5};
    nameptr = (name *)arr;
    nameptr->ptr = arr+2;
    printf("%d ", nameptr->b0);           //prints 1
    printf("%d ", nameptr->b1);           //prints 2
    for (int i=2; i<5; i++){
        printf("%d ",*(nameptr->ptr+i));  //expecting to print 3 4 5
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled I get the below error, Please help me getting this error solved.

*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated

1 2 5 0 56 Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: There are not even layout compatible...

Comment: The correct syntax would be `nameptr->ptr[1]` or `*(nameptr->ptr+1)`, but your struct cannot alias an array.

Comment: Try `uint8_t ptr[];` since you're trying to use it as an array, not a pointer.

Comment: Is `nameptr->*(ptr)` supposed to be `*(nameptr->ptr)`? It's UB anyway (twice actually).

Comment: That's obviously C++. I removed the C tag.

Comment: Is this really C++?

Comment: May I recommend [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)? None of this can work, and I have no idea what are you even trying to do there.

Comment: C or C++? They are slightly different when it comes to wild type casts like `(name *)arr`. It's undefined behavior in both languages, but C has some work-arounds, C++ doesn't.

Comment: @TedLyngmo There are no namespaces and no header `iostream` in C.

Comment: `(name *)` wouldn't work in C either, actually. In C++ it's a type, in C it's a struct tag so `struct name*` is needed.

Comment: @ThomasSablik True ... I'm still feeling reluctant calling this C++ :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo At least it's not C :-)

Comment: @VasudaR Why include `iostream` and then use `std::printf`? You need to include `cstdio` for that.

Comment: The question has been edited. Now I get an error like this
*** stack smashing detected ***:
 ./a.out terminated 5 0 208 Aborted (core dumped)
How can this be resolved?

Comment: I recommend that you follow @Yksisarvinen's advice and pick up a book on C++. Your code is confusing and does illegal things. What is the purpose of the code? Perhaps we can help you to achieve your goal without `reinterpret_cast`s.

Comment: After changing your code it has completely different errors. You won't get a good understaning of how pointers work by guessing. For example `nameptr->ptr = arr+2;` - where does `nameptr->ptr` point now? The loop then starts at 2, so where will `nameptr->ptr+2` then point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the modified code as in revision 6 of the question.

If you have a structure of type `name`, not only a pointer, you can assign the array address to the pointer element `ptr` like this.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

struct name{

    uint8_t b0;
    uint8_t b1;
    uint8_t* ptr;

}*nameptr;

int main()
{

    uint8_t arr[]= {1,2,3,4,5};
    name name_struct; // actual memory where you can access the structure fields
    nameptr = &name_struct; // pointer now points to a real structure of the correct type
    nameptr->ptr = arr; // assign array to pointer inside structure

    /* For this loop you must know the size of the array the pointer is pointing to.
     * Your code cannot automatically derive this information from the
     * pointer element `ptr` or from the structure like you could with
     * sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]). */
    for (int i=2; i<5; i++){
        printf("%d ",*(nameptr->ptr+i));  //expecting to print 3 4 5
        // printf("%d ",nameptr->ptr[i]);  // same, but easier to understand
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code in revision 7 of the question is wrong in several ways:

```
struct name{
    uint8_t b0;
    uint8_t b1;
    uint8_t* ptr;
}*nameptr;

/* Depending on your platform, the structure might be something like this */
struct name_with_padding {
    uint8_t b0; // 1st byte
    uint8_t b1; // 2nd byte
    // uint8_t padding[2]; // 3rd and 4th byte 
    uint8_t* ptr; // 5th to 8th byte
}*nameptr;

uint8_t arr[]= {1,2,3,4,5};

/* This cast is the main error. It will interpret the memory of the array
 * as a structure as shown above which is undefined behavior (and 
 * implementation dependent).
 * It might result in:
 * b0 = 1
 * b1 = 2
 * padding = {3, 4}
 * ptr = value 5 + some (3) bytes after it
 * But it may as well result in other (undefined) behavior.
 */
nameptr = (name *)arr;

/* This may (depending on your implementation) overwrite
 * overwrite the value 5 and the following (3) bytes
 * with the address arr+2
 * so it will change the value of arr[4] and the memory after it
 * This may (or may not) result in a segmentation fauult or stack corruption.
 */ 
nameptr->ptr = arr+2;
```

Comment: This solves my error.. Also, I will edit the indexing part of the array in the question

Comment: @VasudaR Maybe I got you wrong, but you don't need to edit the code in your question to match the answer. Of course you can edit the code you will actually use.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the original code in the first revision of the question and on my interpretation about the intention behind the wrong code.

See also my other answer based on the code in revision 6 of the question.

The structure element `uint8_t* ptr;` is a pointer, not an array. That's why, when doing `nameptr = (name *)arr;` and dereferencing `nameptr->ptr`, you interpret the data in memory as an address and try to access the memory at this address. The address is probably constructed from the bytes 3, 4, 5 and whatever follows it in memory. (implementation dependent)

This modified version *of the original code* might do what you want, **but** casting the array pointer `arr` to a structure pointer and accessing the structure elements is **undefined behavior** and highly depends on your implementation. (There might be padding between the array elements.)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

struct name{

    uint8_t b0;
    uint8_t b1;
    uint8_t array[3];

} name1, *nameptr;

int main()
{
    
    uint8_t arr[]= {1,2,3,4,5};
    nameptr = (name *)arr;
    printf("%d\n",(int)nameptr->b0);
    printf("%d\n",(int)nameptr->b1);
    printf("%d\n",(int)nameptr->array[0]); //should print 3
    printf("%d\n",(int)nameptr->array[1]); //should print 4
    printf("%d\n",(int)nameptr->array[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

On the specific platform where I tested the program, the output is

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

see https://onlinegdb.com/HyY8BDUz_

But in fact it is **undefined behavior** and may produce different results depending on your implementation.

Comment: Can you please make 'uint8_t array[3]' in struct name to 'uint8_t* ptr'? Since I want to access last three elements using the pointer

Comment: "_The output is_"  undefined. Every time the program is executed. @VasudaR What are you really trying to do? Instead of us helping you to paint yourself into a corner - please describe the purpose and someone can probably help you to get there without making programs with undefined behavior.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I wanted to access and print the 3rd,4th and 5th element of the array arr[] using the pointer "ptr" in the "struct name".

Comment: @VasudaR Why do you want to use a pointer to an unrelated type to do so?

Comment: @VasudaR Please explain in your question (instead of in comments) what you want to achieve and what's the intended use case.

Comment: @VasudaR Ok. I hope that the lesson is that even if a program with undefined behavior seems to work the way you hoped Today - you can't be sure that it will do the same Tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Apart the Undefined Behaviour that is invoked by casting an array to a struct, there is a size problem.

This is a slight variation of your code, still invoking UB, hat at least with no runtime error on gcc:

...

```
int main()
{

    uint8_t arr[sizeof(name)]= {1,2,3,4,5};
    nameptr = (name *)arr;
    nameptr->ptr = arr+2;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){  // SB: starting at 2 so only 0 to 3...
        printf("%d ",*(nameptr->ptr+i));  //expecting to print 3 4 5
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And when I execute this code under a debugger, I can see that `arr` has now size 8 (on my 32 bits environment). Because the actual layer of `name` is:

```
* b0
* b1
* padding bytes size 2
* ptr (size 4)
```

So in your original code, when you executed `nameptr->ptr = arr+2;` you were writing well past of the declared array, which is a nice recipe for SIGSEGV or other weird errors.

---

But anyway my code does not print 3, 4, 5. Even if it invokes undefined behaviour, my implementation does write the first byte of `ptr` at the place where was the 5 (see the above layer to understand why...). So I get 3, 4 and a random byte!